# Get the PDF page that contains the PdfTextField

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, pdfsharp

We need to get the PpdfPage that contains an especific PdfTextField, how can we do it?

Code:

```
PdfDocument document = PdfReader.Open("C:\\filex.pdf", PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify);

// Get the root object of all interactive form fields
PdfAcroForm form = document.AcroForm;

// Get all form fields of the whole document
PdfAcroField.PdfAcroFieldCollection fields = form.Fields;

PdfTextField textfield1= (PdfTextField)fields["textfield1"];

//how to get the correct page reference respect the especified field?
PdfPage page = textfield1.Owner.Pages[???];
```

Comment: What library are you using itextsharp?

Comment: According to the tags it's pdfsharp.

Comment: @retslig PdfSharp, we used itextsharp in the past but the PdfSharp licenses are more open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we solved it creating this function:

```
    protected int PaginaCampo(string campofirma, PdfDocument document)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < document.Pages.Count; i++)
    {
        PdfAnnotations anotations = document.Pages[i].Annotations;
        for (int j = 0; j < anotations.Count; j++)
        {
            if (anotations[j].Title != campofirma) continue;
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Not the best solution but it works...if someone adds a better one we will give the correct answer to him/her